# SVN Copy Folder of one SVN Repo to another SVN repo Without Removing History

Tags: svn

I have two svn .

Fist is

```
trunk
     -foldoer 1
     -script
```

and Second one is

```
trunk 
     -webscript
```

Where webscript all files are copy of script. webscript is our main repo which update content live.

I am on **Cent OS 5**

Now after every week , I need to move script content to webscript . Without removing svn info of webscipt. and without conflicting these two svn.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

**I had searched on SO. 
But all solution discussed here for this problem are removing history.**

Comment: This brings me to the question: Why do you have two repositories ?

Comment: The code in webscript are live. So if someone modify code in webscript will be live. 
so we test it on first repo and when it is stable we move it to live (second ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two repositories the only way to achieve this is to do a dump/load of the repositories. This means dump both repositories. Use the [dump merge tools](http://svn.borg.ch/svndumptool/) and reload the repositories. But this means you have downtimes of your repositories and you have to have access to the repository server. If you have no access to the repository there is no way to do this.